# Android : String can not be converted JSON object error while executing task

Tags: android, json, httprequest

Trying to execute the following code, Translation API of google

```
            DefaultHttpClient localDefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams localHttpParams = localDefaultHttpClient.getParams();
            localHttpParams.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, Integer.valueOf(10000));
            localHttpParams.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, Integer.valueOf(10000));
            localHttpParams.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, "utf-8");
            HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(localHttpParams, "AndroidTranslate/2.5.3 2.5.3 (gzip)");
            try {
                str1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localDefaultHttpClient.execute
                        (new HttpPost("https://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=at&sc=1&v=2.0&sl="
                                + Global.lan1 + "&tl=" + Global.lan2 + "&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&text="
                                + URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8"))).getEntity().getContent(), "utf-8"), 8).readLine();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (str1 != null) {
                try {
                    localJSONObject = new JSONObject(str1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Before this code was working fine, but for few days I am getting the following error

```
    W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:169)
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:182)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.length()' on a null object reference
```

Yup, I have searched google and SO for related answer and got some solutions and tried with my code but still i am getting this error, may be i have mistaken somewhere but i don't know where exactly.
Can anyone guide me exactly where is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

`!DOCTYPE` is typically associated with HTML not JSON. Are you sure the API you're calling is returning a JSON and not the HTML page itself. Looking at that google translate URL, it seems that you're getting the HTML page and trying to parse the HTML page as a JSON, hence it's failing.

I would debug `str1` and see what the output of `str1` really is.

Comment: So, what's the solution to convert that page to JSON object, Is there anyway

Comment: Could it be that you were using the Google Translate API and that license expired? So instead of sending you back the JSON from the API, it's sending in some HTML page. I would check the content of `str1` and post it here.

You said it was working before and now it's no longer working right?

Comment: Yes Exactly, It was working before but not now, As you say I have debugged my code and I am getting <!DOCTYPE html> as a result in str1